# exec: "sqlboiler": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: postgresql, go

After installed [SqlBoiler](https://github.com/vattle/sqlboiler).

Copy and paste simple codes in main.go and execute postgresql to create databases.

I generated Go models by doing:

```
go generate
```

I got an error:

```
running "sqlboiler": exec: "sqlboiler": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I've watched [SQLBoiler Screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKmRemtmi0Y&feature=youtu.be) but it's assumed user pre configured Sql Boiler

What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKmRemtmi0Y&feature=youtu.be) starts with

```
go get -u -t github.com/vattle/sqlboiler
```

That step alone should compile and install `sqlboiler` in your `$GOPATH/bin` folder. Make sure that folder is part of your `PATH`.

Comment: hi @VonC, I looked at my Gopath, when i run:

    go get -u -t github.com/vattle/sqlboiler

the sqlboiler binary file located in **/home/go/bin** , but somehow when runing **go generate**, I looked up to **/usr/local/go/bin**. Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are either missing the binary or didn't configure your `$PATH` correctly.

Make sure that `sqlboiler` binary exists in `$GOPATH/bin`. You can do this to verify:

```
> ls $GOPATH/bin/sqlboiler
/home/cglotr/go/bin/sqlboiler
```

If it exists, configure your `$PATH` like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/cglotr/go/bin
```

Now you should be able to use `sqlboiler`.